# Personal proof to the notion that the set of rational numbers is countable

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am not a student of core mathematics and hence as a result, all of my educational (engg.physics) background is based on the notion of applied mathematics rather than core mathematics, but I am attending a lecture in probability theory where the professor proved that the set of rational numbers is bijective to the set of natural numbers and hence the set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

I am trying to prove it in a different way and would like the "core" mathematicians to check if I am making any logical fallacy in my arguments. Here it goes

Let me define $\mathbb{N}^2$ as
$$\mathbb{N}^2=\left\{(x,y)|x,y\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$$
Hence, I claim that $\mathbb{N}^2$ is countable, since $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}^2$ is clearly bijective.
Now, I define
$$\mathbb{Q}=\left\{\frac{p}{q}|(p,q)\in\mathbb{N}^2\right\}$$
Since, $f:\mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{Q}$ is clearly surjective and $\mathbb{N}^2$ is countable, that implies that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable

Is this proof of mine logically correct? If not, please let me know if I have assumed something somewhere where I should not have assumed stuff. Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: You haven't defined the $f$'s?

Comment: As a general piece of advice, any time you set out to deepen your understanding of a mathematical theorem by giving your own rigorous proof, it's a good idea to avoid using the word "clearly." Stop instead and ask yourself just exactly what makes the thing you're saying so clear. In many cases (and this is one such case), the point that seems "clear" is the actual crux of the proof -- and sometimes isn't so clear after all!

Comment: Let me add to my previous comment that your instinct to deepen your understanding by giving your own alternative proof is admirable and to be encouraged. Keep it up!

Comment: Your $f: \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{Q}$ is not 'clearly surjective'. Rationals include negatives!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not correct, because:

- you did not define any of the $f$'s;
- the set $\left\{\frac pq\,\middle|\,(p,q)\in\Bbb N^2\right\}$ is not equal to $\Bbb Q$; it is equal to $\{q\in\Bbb Q\mid q>0\}$.

Comment: ahaa....ok, I understand the second comment, since I don't take into account the negative rationals if $(p,q)\in\mathbb{N}^2$, but for the first comment, could you please elaborate how the definition of $f$'s could be done in either case in keeping with "core mathematical notations"??

Comment: If you want us to check the proof, then it's up to you to define the functions.

Comment: @ubuntu_noob Also, it's a bad idea to overload variable names: use $f$ for one function and, say, $g$ for the other.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Could you help me by showing how the variable definition/mapping can be shown. I actually meant to index the values I got out of $\mathbb{Q}$ using $\mathbb{N}^2$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Doesn't the mapping, $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}^2$ define the function, $f$? I meant to say it like $\mathbb{N}^2=\left\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(0,2),(1,2),(2,2).....\right\}$ can be indexed using $\mathbb{N}=\left\{0,1,2,3,4.....\right\}$ like a list.....How would you, as a pure mathematician, expect me to write this statement in mathematical language per se??

Comment: I don't even know what the question “Doesn't the mapping, $f\colon\Bbb N\longrightarrow\Bbb N^2$ define the function $f$?” *means*. If you want us to understand your work concerning a function $f$, then tell us how that function is defined.